# Javascript regex, getting error when removing all single quotes except for those that precede an s

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that works in RegExr, but is throwing an Invalid Group exception in the browser. I'm attempting to remove all single quotes, with the exception of those that precede an s, as in cat's. I'm not sure where the issue is coming from. BTW, as you can see, I'm also removing any -- and and # symbols and their hex partners.

```
return str.replace(/(\%27)|(?<![a-z])'|'(?!s\b)|(\-\-)|(\%23)|(#)/gi, "-restricted-");
```

Thanks...

Comment: What about: `they're`, `didn't`, `we've` (or even possibly: `shouldn't've`) and other similar contractions?

Comment: @ridgerunner. Thanks for the feed back. Copying the solution for s shouldn't be a problem right? Simply need to add logic for each character allowed.

Comment: Possibly. Try it and see! (Note: To get an in-depth answer, you need to provide an in-depth description of _exactly_ what you are trying to accomplish - complete with specific examples of input, desired output, what you've tried, error messages you've received, etc.) Regexes are very precise and problem descriptions need to be very precise as well.

Comment: Here is the final revision that works for us! /<[^>]+>|(?:^|[^a-z])'|'(?![a-z]{1,2}\b)|-{2}|[^A-Za-z0-9\s-@%$&!?\.,_'"]/g Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<![a-z])` is the problem, because lookbehind doesn't exist in javascript. If you want make some test for regex in javascript, use an online tool for javascript like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).

I don't know what you are trying to do but you can try this code:

```
return str.replace(/%2[37]|(^|[^a-z])'|'(?!s\b)|--|#/gi, "$1-restricted-");
```

I have replaced the negative lookbehind `(?<![a-z])` *(ie: not preceded by a letter)* by a capturing group `(^|[^a-z])` *(ie: begining of the string OR a character that is not a letter)*. Since it is not a simple check like a lookaround but a match, the replace will delete this "non-letter", then I put a reference in the replacement pattern to this first capturing group (`$1`) to replace it by itself.

Comment: That would do it! Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @user2250351: try the code from my edit. but i don't understand what you want to do with quotes.

Comment: I'm porting from java on the server to js. We want to avoid users adding characters that will fail on the server's char check without going through a request. Can you enlighten on what you did at the end ($1)? I like the hex check you did in the beginning.

Comment: Perfect! I forgot that you can access the capture group from regex as a var $1. Wish I worked with these more often. Our final version on the server removes capturing using ?: at the head of the block. Thanks again.